# Lost Team features in Visual Studio 2015 update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2015

After upgrading to Update 3 I lost all team services related features: the queries, linking commits to work items, etc. How can I fix that? (I have VS2015 enterprise edition)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, after while I closed the solution and reopened it from the main menu File->Open->Team Project... Strange.